# Invalid operands to binary expression while implementing vector

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

In an assigment, I was asked to create my own `Vector<T>`, `Mathvector<T>` (which inherits from vector) and a `Polynomial` class type.
I'm getting the following error and couldn't figure out why.

```
MathVector.h:37:32: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('mathVector<double>' and 'mathVector<double>')
                if (this[j]>this[j+1])
```

Ihe sort function is in "mathVector.h" and its goal is to sort the vector in ascending or descending order.

**This is the error part of the "MathVector.h":**

```
void sort(int index) {
        int i,j;
        int n=this->get_size();
        if (index==1) {
            for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
                for (j=0; j<n-i-1; j++) {

                    if (this[j]>this[j+1]) {
                        T temp;
                        temp=this[j+1];
                        this[j+1]=this[j];
                        this[j]=temp;
                    }
                }
        }
        else {
            for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
                for (j=0; j<n-i-1; j++) {
                    if (this[j]<this[j+1]) {
                        T temp;
                        temp=this[j+1];
                        this[j+1]=this[j];
                        this[j]=temp;
                    }
                }
        }
        return;
    }
```

**This is the "vector.h":**

```
template<class T>
class Vector {
private:
    int _size;
    int _capacity;
    T *_data;

    static T *allocate(int size) {
        return static_cast<T *>(malloc(sizeof(T) * size));
    }

    static void copyRange(T *begin, T *end, T *dest) {
        while (begin != end) {
            new((void *) dest) T(*begin);
            ++begin;
            ++dest;
        }
    }

    static void deleteRange(T *begin, T *end) {
        while (begin != end) {
            begin->~T();
            ++begin;
        }
    }

public:

    Vector() {
        _size = 0;
        _capacity = 0;
        _data = 0;
    }

    ~Vector() {
        deleteRange(_data, _data + _size);
        free(_data);
    }

    Vector(const Vector &obj) {
        this->_size = obj.get_size();
        this->_data = obj.get_data();
        this->_capacity = obj.get_capacity();
    }

    void insert(const T &value) {
        if (_size != _capacity) {
            new((void *) (_data + _size)) T(value);
            ++_size;
            return;
        }
        int newCapacity;
        if (_capacity == 0) { newCapacity = 1; }
        else (newCapacity = _capacity * 2);
        T *newData = allocate(newCapacity);
        copyRange(_data, _data + _size, newData);
        new((void *) (newData + _size)) T(value);
        deleteRange(_data, _data + _size);
        free(_data);
        _data = newData;
        _capacity = newCapacity;
        ++_size;
    }

    void resize(int index) {
        if (index == _capacity) { return; }
        else if (index > _capacity) { _capacity = index; }
        else {
            _capacity = index;
            if (index < _size) {
                deleteRange(_data + index, _data + _size);
                _size = index;
            }
        }
    }

    T &operator[](int index) {
        T empty;
        if ((index < 0) || (index >= _size)) {
            cout<<"Wrong Index";
            return empty;
        }
        return _data[index];
    }

    const T &
    operator[](int index) const {
        T empty;
        if ((index < 0) || (index >= _size)) {
            cout<<"Wrong Index";
            return empty;
        } else return _data[index];
    }

    Vector &operator=(const Vector &other) {
        this->_size = other.get_size();
        this->_data = other.get_data();
        this->_capacity = other.get_capacity();
        return *this;
    }


    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Vector &other) {
        os << "Size: " << other._size << " | Capacity: " << other._capacity << " | ";
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < other._size; i++) {
            os << other[i] << ",";
        }
        return os;
    }

    T *begin() const {
        return _data;
    }

    T *end() const {
        return _data + _size;
    }

    int get_size() const {
        return _size;
    }

    T* get_data() const {
        return _data;
    }

    int get_capacity() const {
        return _capacity;
    }
};
```

Comment: `*URGENT*`---> asking for DV.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry to say, but your urgency has nothing to do with people investing their time. Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: `this[j]` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @SouravGhosh about the URGENT i apologize, i appreciate the help, its the first time im asking a question here, i edited

Answer (score 2):

`this[j]` is hardly ever the right thing to do. It can only be correct, if `*this` happens to be a subobject within an array, and have at least `j` siblings after it. `this[j]` is equivalent to `*(this + j)`. As you can see, it dereferences a pointer to `j`th sibling after `*this`.

I suspect, that you instead intended to access the elements of the buffer by calling `Vector::operator[]`. You'd do that by dereferencing the pointer first: `(*this)[j]`.

Comment: First of all `this` does not exist there as `sort` not a method of a class.

Comment: @Slava You can't know that unless you've seen the context where it was declared. I haven't seen the context either, but according to the error message, `*this` appears to be of type `mathVector<double>`.

Comment: context is provided, source of standalone function `sort` is there.

Comment: @Slava I looked into my crystal ball and saw that the provided code is incomplete and that you have been mislead by OP. However, I understand your confusion; the question is not of high quality.